# SQL to track changes of a record without using physical Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-data-capture

I need to write a SQL query to track changes of the same records vs the previous status of each row using temp tables because I need to put them in a third-party. I know I can write these into a table and always compare them back but in this scenario, but this scenario does not let me have a physical table to keep historical data.

```
SELECT CENTRE, CODE, Fromdate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CENTRE ORDER BY  Fromdate desc) AS RN,
FROM #Raw_Table
ORDER BY RN ASC, Fromdate desc
```

As an example, below is a subset of data. I have CENTRE , its CODE and its FROMDATE... nowif in the next run of the QUERY (next date) , the CODE value of 21/07/2023 changes from 6 to 2, I need this to be in the final output. other rows will need to be ignored if no changes.

Query output : 15/8/2023

| CENTRE | CODE | Fromdate | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/07/2023 | 1 |
| 7918 | 6 | 24/04/2023 | 2 |
| 7918 | 6 | 26/01/2023 | 3 |
| 7918 | 6 | 26/10/2022 | 4 |
| 7918 | 6 | 26/07/2022 | 5 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/02/2022 | 6 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/11/2021 | 7 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/08/2021 | 8 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/06/2021 | 9 |
| 7918 | 6 | 15/06/2021 | 10 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/04/2021 | 11 |

Query output : 17/8/2023

| CENTRE | CODE | Fromdate | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7918 | 2 | 21/07/2023 | 1 |
| 7918 | 6 | 24/04/2023 | 2 |
| 7918 | 6 | 26/01/2023 | 3 |
| 7918 | 6 | 26/10/2022 | 4 |
| 7918 | 3 | 26/07/2022 | 5 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/02/2022 | 6 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/11/2021 | 7 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/08/2021 | 8 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/06/2021 | 9 |
| 7918 | 6 | 15/06/2021 | 10 |
| 7918 | 6 | 21/04/2021 | 11 |

Desired Output after second run

| CENTRE | CODE | Fromdate | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7918 | 2 | 21/07/2023 | 1 |
| 7918 | 3 | 26/07/2022 | 5 |

**Shortcoming of my current query:**

1. How to spot those two records in the final output?
2. I don't know how to keep historical data without storing all outputs in a physical table. Is there any way to keep changes in a global temp table or any other method?

Comment: Please show, separately, your sample data, and your desired results. And also explain what about your currently query doesn't work?

Comment: To track changes in SQL Server without manually creating new (user) objects, turn on CDC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 It creates a bunch of system objects

Comment: *Is there any way to keep changes in a global temp table* = No, even with CDC on you have (non-temp) objects in use. So no magic of the sort you are seeking.